# How to use time format on Java

Tags: java

I have 2 variables: first variable for hours and second variable for minutes. But format for this data is "24 hours", but I need resulting string similar "5:30 pm".

How can I format my time for this format?

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have the hours and minutes as variables, date and date format objects might be overkill.  You can use a method like this:

```
public String getTimeString(int hours, int minutes)
{
    String AmPm = "AM";
    if(hours > 12)
    {
        hours -= 12;
        AmPm = "PM";
    }
    return String.format("%d:%02d %s", hours, minutes, AmPm);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    formatTime(1, 23);
    formatTime(11, 33);
    formatTime(14, 43);
}

private static void formatTime(int hours, int minutes) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Output will be:

> 01:23 PM 
>   11:33 PM 
>   02:43 AM